# AWS Lambda Promise.all is never returning or await is not working with it

Tags: lambda, promise, async-await, aws-sdk-js

So I have the below code.  When I run it locally it works as expected.  When I publish it to lambda it fails to get my S3 items.  I see that the promises get created for my request but the `return Promise.all(ps)` never returns with the expected values.  I have tried to change it in a few different ways but always nothing.  I updated my local env to be the same as lambda (node 8.10 and aws-sdk 2.290.0) and still it works locally but not when hosted.

The cloudwatch logs show that it ended and does not contain errors and ends in ~100ms.

I'm calling out to get 20 objects from s3 each 8k in size; I have added a break to only retrieve 1 record and the same happens... nothing.

```
module.exports = async(messages) => {
  try {

    for (var rec of messages) {
      debug('rec',rec);
      let samples = await getRecordingPageSamples(rec.serialNumber,rec.recordingSet,rec.recording,rec.pages);
      //NEVER GETS HERE IN LAMBDA
      ...
    }
    //NEVER GETS HERE IN LAMBDA
    console.log('we are done here.');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('unhandled',e);
  }
};

function getRecordingPageSamples(serialNumber,recordingSet,recording,pages){
  let ps = getObjectGenerator(pages.map(x=>[process.env.s3EeegPageBucket,genRecordingSamplePath(serialNumber,recordingSet,recording,x)]));
  ps = ps.map( p=> p.then(obj=>{
    console.log('done',obj[1]);
    return obj.slice(0,2).concat([obj[1].split(s.FILE_NAME_SEP)[2],obj[2].Body.toString()]);
  }));
  // here ps is an array of promises ps [ Promise { <pending> } ]
  return Promise.all(ps);
}

function getObjectGenerator(list){
  let ps = [];
  for (let x of list){
    //DOES GET HERE IN LAMBDA
    console.log('requesting obj',x);
    ps.push( getObject(x[0],x[1]));
  }
  return ps;
}

const getObject = (bucket,key) => {
  return s3.getObject({
    Bucket: bucket, // Assuming this is an environment variable...
    Key: key
  })
    .promise()
    .then(data=>{
      //NEVER GETS HERE IN LAMBDA
      console.log('got it',key);
      return [bucket,key,data];
    });
```

---

Problem solved.  There was another wrapper function above this module that was an async function but was not using the await keyword.  Rookie mistake!

Comment: Are you correctly waiting for the top-level function from your lambda handler function?

Comment: @Evert you are my GD hero... There I go trying to reuse code and I miss the await while the containing function was async. Cheers!

Comment: Glad I could help! Something I ran into myself too =) it probably helps to have a good way to run this on a local box. Makes it more obvious to see when the handler function ends.

Comment: I am running it locally but that seemed to run to completion.  I was starting to track it down because I added more logging that showed the finally was run prior to the promises completing.  I guess the only way to make this happen locally in a similar fashion would be to create another wrapper that kills the node process after the handler returns.  Any thought on how to do that?

Comment: I know there's tools that do all this for you, but the way I did it is to just have a little bit out of output after the handler returned. `process.exit()` is more aggressive but could also work.

Comment: I don't like having too much tooling, but there's things out there that are specifically for testing microservices locally.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. There was another wrapper function above this module that was an async function but was not using the await keyword. Rookie mistake!  Thanks @Evert